# Can Identityserver4 use for Open banking Authorisation Server Implementation?

Tags: identityserver4

I am implementing the Open Banking for my company and used the Identityserver4 for implementing the authorization server. I just want to know whether a bank or a financial services company has used the Identityserver4 for implementing the open banking authorisation server.

Comment: Hi Chandra,
I have used Identityserver4 in two financial services companies.

Comment: Use WSO2 IS or WSO2 IS as KM